# mongodb network failed trying to connect

Tags: mongodb

Any prerequisite to run mongodb? I installed on windows and it can't run when I type in mongo command in my cmd. I already tried to run with administrator.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have typed the wrong command on the command line.The command you should enter is `mongod`

Comment: I did, then? what to do next?

Comment: If you can see at the bottom `waiting for connections on port 27017`, your db has been up.
If you are a beginner refer some tutorials

Comment: I solved it, so everytime have to open 2 cmd?

Comment: Yes you have to keep open the cmd while you work.Try Rockmongo it will make your work easier.

Comment: wow is that a GUI for mongo? looks good!